# SQL Group by Query with join

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot

**[Please click here for sample tables and description.](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=588&d=1336691473)**

I have three tables ‘PROJECTS’, 'PROJECTMANAGER' and ‘MANAGERS' as per attached images.

I need a query which can list PROJECTS managed by “PRODUCT” type managers grouped with PROJECT STATUS. 
If STATUS=2 then show as Completed Projects or else In Progress Projects.

Resulted table should look like as shown in attached image.
Desired Result: http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=588&d=1336691473

The query, I need should be generic so that it can be used in any database (MySQL/Oracle/MSSQL/DB2)

Please Help.

BTW, This is not the homework...!!!!
I used sample tables.

I have tried with case when statements but don't know how to join and at the same time use group by.

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECTS 
(       
    PROJECT_ID  varchar(20), 
    PROJECT_NAME  varchar(30),
    STATUS int
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECTMANAGER
(
    PROJECT_ID  varchar(20), 
    MANAGER_ID varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE MANAGERS
(           
    MANAGER_ID  varchar(20), 
    MANAGER_NAME  varchar(20), 
    TYPE varchar(20)
);


INSERT INTO PROJECTS (PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_NAME, STATUS) VALUES
    ('project_001', 'Project 001', 0),
    ('project_002', 'Project 002', 1),
    ('project_003', 'Project 003', 2),
    ('project_004', 'Project 004', 0),
    ('project_005', 'Project 005', 2),
    ('project_006', 'Project 006', 0),
    ('project_007', 'Project 007', 1);


INSERT INTO PROJECTMANAGER (PROJECT_ID , MANAGER_ID) VALUES
    ('project_001', 'mgr_001'),
    ('project_002', 'mgr_001'),
    ('project_001', 'mgr_002'),
    ('project_002', 'mgr_003'),
    ('project_001', 'mgr_003'),
    ('project_005', 'mgr_001'),
    ('project_004', 'mgr_002');

INSERT INTO MANAGERS (MANAGER_ID, MANAGER_NAME, TYPE) VALUES
    ('mgr_001', 'Manager 001', 'PRODUCT'),
    ('mgr_002', 'Manager 002', 'HR'),
    ('mgr_003', 'Manager 003', 'PRODUCT'),
    ('mgr_004', 'Manager 004', 'FINANCE'),
    ('mgr_005', 'Manager 005', 'PRODUCT');



Resulted Table:

MANAGER_ID  | MANAGER _NAME | COMPLETED_PROJECTS |  IN_PROGRESS_PROJECTS |
 mgr_001    | Manager 001   |        1       |            2          |
 mgr_003    | Manager 003   |        0       |            1          |
 mgr_005    | Manager 005   |        0       |            0          |
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can't see the end result that you want (there is no image posted) then you could do something like this:

```
select p.project_id
  , p.project_name
  , m.manager_name
  , case when p.status = 2 then 'completed' else 'in progress' end as projectstatus
from projects p
left join projectmanager pm
  on p.project_id = pm.project_id
left join managers m
  on pm.manager_id = m.manager_id
WHERE m.type = 'Product'
```

[SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b49e/14)

I think you are wanting the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
    select m.manager_id
      , m.manager_name
      , status
      , case when status = '2' then 'Completed' else 'in progress' end as pstatus
    from projects p
    left join projectmanager pm
      on p.project_id = pm.project_id
    left join managers m
      on pm.manager_id = m.manager_id
    WHERE m.type = 'Product'
  ) x
  pivot
  (
    count(status)
    for pstatus in ([completed], [in progress])
  ) p
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b49e/50)

Comment: I have updated image. I tried manipulating your query to get results as desired but couldn't able to.

Comment: I don't see an updated image. Can you post the desired results in in question?

Comment: Desired Results:http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=588&d=1336691473

Comment: your desired results looks the same as your original image

Comment: In that image there is, Resulted table at the bottom of the image.

Comment: When I load the image, there is no result table - it only shows the projects, projectmanager and manager table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables together with INNER JOINs (Project to Projectmanager using project_id, and projectmanager to manager using manager_id).

Then group it all together with GROUP BY

Also read up on the T-SQL CASE statement. You need it (or an IF) to convert the STATUS field into 'Completed' or 'Not Completed'.